# Bootstrap3 confirm modal callback triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The code I used below works fine for first time.When I click cancel and press delete again ,function is called two times..In below example i get alert two times.I tried return false , still same problem.

Below is the javascript code

```
$(document).on("click",'.delbuttfultrackconfirm', function(e){


    $('#delfultrackconfirm')
        .modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        .one('click', '#delfultrackconfirmdel', function (e) {
           alert("delete");

        });


});
```

Hello below is the html code

```
<!-- Modal --> 
<div class="modal fade" id="delfultrackconfirm" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delfultrackconfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div id="delfultrackconfirmbody" class="modal-body"> Are you sure want to delete this </div>
         <div class="modal-footer"> <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="delfultrackconfirmdel">Delete</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button> </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<center><button class="delbuttfultrackconfirm" href="#">del</button></center>
```

Here is bootply http://www.bootply.com/1Ghug4eX7p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put the click function of the button outside the '. delbuttfultrackconfirm' click, like this

```
$(".delbuttfultrackconfirm").click(function(e){
    $('#delfultrackconfirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
});

$('#delfultrackconfirmdel').click(function (e) {
       alert("delete");
});
```

The problem is your code is that every time you open the modal and not click on the "delete" button, you're adding another handler to be executed on the first click on the button.

Read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 1):

This is because after each click you append event handler. This is happen because element store array of handlers, and after two clicks you have 2 handlers and each will be called.

> function (e) {
>          alert("delete");
>   }

To avoid this just move handler to top;

```
$(".delbuttfultrackconfirm").click(function(e){
    $('#delfultrackconfirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
});

$('#delfultrackconfirmdel').click(function (e) {
       alert("delete");
});
```

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/wA36GhaqJg)